# What is /etc/docker/key.json ?

Tags: docker

It looks like it contains a bunch of hashes but i cant seem to figure out what its for.

Would there be any harm in it being lost ?

Does it contain sensitive information ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the dockerd key for TLS connections, in web format, that docker uses when connecting to other TLS servers like registries. It's automatically generated by the docker engine on startup, so there's no risk if deleted. You should treat it as sensitive since TLS connections using an exposed key are not secure.

More details are available here: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7667

Comment: What is the risk if someone has write permissions to this file? because you can already read it.

Comment: @E235 the file is only readable by root on my system. You don't want anyone else to have read or write to this file, otherwise the TLS encryption is compromised or broken from docker to external systems (mainly registry servers).